# Como obter o conteúdo de arquivo javascript na forma de string?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Estou fazendo um programa que necessita ler o código-fonte de um arquivo javascript. Eu estava tentando obter o arquivo javascript via XMLHttpRequest e retornar o `this.responseText`, no entanto, seu valor é `undefined`.
Como faço para retornar o conteúdo de um arquivo javascript na forma de string(sem jQuery ou, preferencialmente, sem o uso de bibliotecas de terceiros)?

Segue o código abaixo

```
function getScriptStr(filepath) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            return this.responseText.split('\n');
        }
    };
        http.open("GET", filepath, true);
        http.send();
};
```

Comment: Renomeie o arquivo que você quer importar de ".js" para ".txt"

Comment: @inovapixel não posso, o objetivo é exatamente ele ler arquivos javascript

Comment: O XMLHttpRequest não executa o código... O código retornado é um text/json, text/plain ou outro MIME.  Você não pode simplesmente incluir o seu arquivo no documento HTML?

Comment: Você não deveria ter muitas dificuldades em fazer isso, mas a uma limitação.
Se o arquivo JS não estiver no seu servidor pode ser que você não tenha acesso para fazer essa requisição. De qualquer forma, posta o seu código aqui para que a gente possa ajudar. Abraço

Comment: @inovapixel eu sei que ele não executa, no entanto, não entendo porque ele retorna undefined, se o arquivo é encontrado

Comment: Porque o XMLHttpRequest retorna texto plano, e não o arquivo em si. Se você conseguisse retornar o ".js", seria apenas o texto que está contido nele, sendo assim, tanto faz ser ".txt" ou ".js"

Comment: @inovapixel sim, mas para mim está retornando undefined.

Comment: Cara, mas se tanto faz, não vai adiantar você pegar o ".js".  Acho que retorna "undefined" por arquivos ".js" não serem aceitos pelo XHR. Não tenho certeza, mas acho que não são aceitos, não.

Comment: @GabrielC. aqui no site não colocamos a pergunta como respondida, você ou marca uma resposta como correta ou responde à sua própria pergunta e marca como correta.

Comment: @inovapixel Tudo bem, já resolvi o problema =)

Comment: @JorgeB. perdão, sou novo no site. Acho que vou responder minha própria pergunta então.

Comment: @GabrielC. na boa, ninguém nasce ensinado. E seja bem-vindo ao site :)

Comment: @inovapixel XHR aceita sim arquivos js

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza Entendi. Como eu falei, não tinha certeza, foi apenas palpite por estar retornando o "undefined".

Comment: Também não tinha certeza, fiz uns testes aqui para confirmar, o único erro que tive foi de CORS, mas fora isso consegui pegar qualquer conteúdo por XHR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ao utilizar **`XMLHttpRequest`** assíncrono você deves utilizar uma função de `callback` para retornar a resposta (caso haja) pois return sempre retornara `undefined` pois ele não espera "a resposta" da requisição.

**Exemplo:**

```
´´´javascript

// instanciar a API
var XHR = ( new XMLHttpRequest() );

// função
var requestGet = function(url, callback){
    // catch response
    XHR.onreadystatechange = function(){
         if( XHR.readyState == 4 && XHR.status == 200 ){
             if( callback ){
                 callback(XHR.responseText);
             }
         }
    };
    // open
    XHR.open('GET', url, true);
    // check
    if( !url || typeof url !== 'string' || url.length < 2 ){
        return false;
    }else{
        // send
        XHR.send();
    }
};

// uso:
requestGet('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js', function(res){
    if ( res !== false ) {
         console.log(res);
    }
});
```

Caso queira utilizar (importar) `strings` no formato `json` deves utilizar `JSON.parse()` para transformar estas `strings` em objetos `javascript` novamente.

**Exemplo:**

```
´´´json
{
     "a": "abacaxi",
     "b": "bola",
     "c": "carambola"
}

´´´javascript
// variavel pré-definida
var xmlhttpObj;

// no retorno do "callback"
if ( res !== false ) {
     xmlhttpObj = JSON.parse(res);
}

// posteriormente
console.log(xmlhttpObj.c); //output: carambola
```

Caso queira saber mais, dados técnicos da API, suporte e outros exemplos vale a pena dar uma olhada nas referencias da [Mozila (sync|async)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Requisicoes_sincronas_e_assincronas) assim como [Mozila XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Ótima resposta, isso explica porque o return não estava funcionando corretamente, dado que a variável necessitava de um retorno imediato da função, e como essa era assíncrona, não podia retornar imediatamente o valor necessário, isso esclareceu muito, obrigado. Desse modo substituo o return pela atribuição de valor e coloco os passos seguintes juntamente com a função callback.