# Como usar uma única função jQuery sem importar toda a biblioteca?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou fazendo uma **extensão para Firefox** e nela eu importo a **JQuery** todinha. No projeto eu só uso a função `getJSON();`.

Dei uma procurada na net e não encontrei muita coisa. Pesquisei nos repositórios github e encontrei alguns, porém não sei se são confiáveis ou se existe alguma solução mais viável.

Por isso queria saber se existe algum jeito de só importar a função que eu uso ao invés de toda a biblioteca, tornando meu código muito melhor.

Comment: Podes procurar soluções em javascript ("puro") equivalentes as suas funções que esta habituado a usar em `jQuery`

Comment: Se o método de requisição for `GET` talvez esta pergunta lhe ajude: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188577/como-obter-o-conte%C3%BAdo-de-arquivo-javascript-na-forma-de-string/188834#188834

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função `jQuery.getJson()` é um *alias* pra uma chamada AJAX HTTP GET, ou seja, você apenas está usando o método `ajax()` da biblioteca, portanto você está usando apenas uma chamada assíncrona e recebendo um JSON como resposta, correto?

Para fazer o mesmo sem importar toda a biblioteca você pode usar `XMLHttpRequest` que é o que o método `jQuery.ajax()` (e seu derivado `jQuery.getJSON()`) usa, já que o mesmo é apenas um wrapper.

Enquanto com jQuery você faria

```
$.ajax('service/user/1234', {
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    processData: false,
    data: JSON.stringify({
        name: 'João de Barros',
        age: 34
    })
})
.then(function success(userInfo) {
    // userInfo será um objeto contendo propriedades como nome, idade, 
    // endereço, etc.
});
```

Com XMLHttpRequest você faria assim

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'service/user/1234');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        var userInfo = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        // userInfo será o mesmo objeto contendo propriedades como nome, 
        // idade, endereço, etc.
    }
};
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    name: 'João de Barros',
    age: 34
}));
```

Ref.:

- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
- https://blog.garstasio.com/you-dont-need-jquery/ajax/

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado! Obrigado pelos links, ajudaram no entendimento. Porém utilizei o método GET. Estou com outro problema em relação a formatação do texto. Quando eu pego os dados antes de usar o JSONparse, o texto possui /n/t, as formatações originais da fonte. Porém quando transformo para JSON e imprimo no DOM elas somem. Perdem toda a formatação. Sabes de algo?

Comment: O valor String não perde as quebras de linha `\n`, `\r\n` e tabulações `\t`, as mesmas são escapadas, mas o JSON em si é serializado e minificado (tem a formatação removida). Você está perdendo a formatação de uma String que é um valor dentro do JSON ou a formatação do JSON antes de transformar em objeto?