# Funcao Javascript retorna errado Ajax

Tags: ajax, echo

Estou validando um cadastro com JS.

Há uma parte assim:

```
...
if( existUser() ){
   alert(' Email já cadastrado.');
}
else // ok , envia formulario !
```

A função Js que verifica se existe o usuário, chama um PHP, acessa o banco de dados, e se existe ou não ecoa uma string "true" ou "false", respectivamente.

```
function existUser(){
 var e = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var ajax = getAjax(function(){
        if (ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200){
            return ajax.responseText=="true";    // retorno correto
        }
    });
    ajax.open("GET","busca.php?email="+e,true);
    ajax.send();
    return true; // a rotina esta caindo aqui dando retorno errado
}
```

- Se no retorno final coloco True, ele diz que existe um email que não existe
- se deixo como False, diz que não existe um email que existe
- e testei ate deixar null ou sem retorno nesse final. Ai cadastra email existente.
- Eu sei que da pra fazer essa verificação em PHP antes de jogar no banco, mas desejo fazer em Javascript.
- Se alguém puder dar uma opinião agradeço.

---

UPDATED: Pesoal, Obrigado pelas explicações consegui entender do porque não funcionava.!

Consegui uma solução parcial, aqui divido com todos.
Não consegui obter a variável diretamente, para a checagem (if), mas fiz um macete.

Ao receber a string do PHP, dentro do ajax guardo a variável em um input escondido ( `input[type=hidden]` )

```
  &lt;input  type="hidden" name="rs" id="rs" value="">
```

e o js:

```
...
if (ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200){
        document.getElementById('rs').value = ajax.responseText; //guarda valor
        }
   });
    ajax.open("GET","busca.php?email="+e,true);
    ajax.send();
    return document.getElementById('rs').value.toString()=="true"; // o obtêm 
}
```

no campo (input) de email coloquei um evento para já chamar a função quando o usúario termina de digitar o email

```
  &lt;input  type="text" name="email" id="email" onblur="existUser()">
```

Assim, já é chamado o PHP antes do usuário clicar em enviar.

No tratamento Javascript mantive p mesmo

```
...
if( existUser() ){
   alert(' Email já cadastrado.');
}
else // ok , envia formulario !
```

Quando o usuário clicar e executar a rotina novamente , já vai ter tempo de ter feito uma checagem e salva no input.
Realizei diversos testes aqui e funcionou.

Mas pra deixar completo e mais "blindado" vou fazer esse tratamento no PHP também para não cadastrar com email repetido :+)

Valeu !!

Comment: ajax executa de forma assincrona e a forma que voce fez esta estruturada de forma síncrona... voce precisa executar o retorno de mensagem ou envio do formulario ... dentro do retorno da sua resposta do ajax

Comment: voçê deve usar uma função de callback para pegar o retorno. Aqui uma resposta relacionada: [http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188577/](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188577/)